# Python teradatasql get column_name and data_type

Tags: python, python-3.x, teradatasql

I am using `teradatasql` to connect DB and get the table definition. Below is my code which returns the definition for table. Here I trying find any default function which returns the colum_name and data_type of table as a separate function.

```
with teradatasql.connect ('{"host":"whomooz","user":"guest","password":"please"}') as con:
    with con.cursor () as cur:
    try:
                sRequest = "show table MYTABLE"
                print(sRequest)
                cur.execute(sRequest)
                [print(row) for row in sorted(cur.fetchall())]
            except Exception as ex:
                print("Ignoring", str(ex).split("\n")[0])
```

here I am looking for any inbuilt function which can return `column_name` and `data_type`.

output should be like

customer_name  VARCHAR

address    VARCHAR

type SMALLINT

I looked at the teradatasql [docs](https://pypi.org/project/teradatasql/) but did not find any reference

Comment: You can query [dbc.ColumnsV](https://docs.teradata.com/r/ANYCOtbX9Q1iyd~Uiok8gA/GQEcUS4PIFPa9D3bD4xqUA)   though you will need to decode the ColumnType codes (e.g. CV = VARCHAR, I2 = SMALLINT). HELP TABLE is another option but again returns Type codes.

Answer (score 1):

We offer a [sample program](https://github.com/Teradata/python-driver/blob/master/samples/MetadataFromPrepare.py) that demonstrates how to prepare a SQL request and use the `fake_result_sets` feature to obtain result set column metadata and question-mark parameter marker metadata.

See below for example code that prepares a `select *` for a table in conjunction with `fake_result_sets` and prints the result set column metadata.

```
import json
import teradatasql
with teradatasql.connect ('{"host":"whomooz","user":"guest","password":"please"}') as con:
    with con.cursor () as cur:
        cur.execute ("{fn teradata_rpo(S)}{fn teradata_fake_result_sets}select * from dbc.dbcinfo")
        [ print ("DatabaseName={} TableName={} ColumnName={} TypeName={}".format (m ["DatabaseName"], m ["ObjectName"], m ["Name"], m ["TypeName"])) for m in json.loads (cur.fetchone () [7]) ]
```

Prints the following:

```
DatabaseName=DBC TableName=dbcinfo ColumnName=InfoKey TypeName=VARCHAR
DatabaseName=DBC TableName=dbcinfo ColumnName=InfoData TypeName=VARCHAR
```